# ASP.NET framework MVC5 empty project NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget-package

I'm currently learning MVC5 and I'm stuck with NuGet packages. Actually I want to add some NuGet packages like bootstrap to visual studio 2019 community edition and use it for all projects and solutions but I don't know how to do this. Every time I create a new project I have to install the package again.
Anyone help me please I want to install the package at once and not again and again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is to create your own custom project template with this package already installed.

Try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2019